# If $P(0) = 3$ and $60P'(t) = P(t)[12 - P(t)]$, for what value of $P$ is the function increasing the fastest?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following differential equations are from a past AP test.

a.) If $P(0) = 3$ and $60P'(t) = P(t)[12 - P(t)]$, for what value of $P$ is the function increasing the fastest?
b.) Solve the differential equation $60Q'(t) = Q(t)[12 - t]$ if $Q(0) = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$a)$: hint:  You are looking to find the max of $P'(t)$. You have $P''(t) = 12P'(t) - 2P(t)P'(t) = \dfrac{12P(t) - P(t)^2}{5}- \dfrac{12P^2(t)-P^3(t)}{30}= 0$. So you can now solve this cubic equation to find $P(t)$ which gives the max of $P'(t)$. Can you find a factor of the left hand side? I hope you can.

$b)$ hint: $\dfrac{Q'(t)}{Q(t)} = \dfrac{12-t}{60}\implies \displaystyle \int \dfrac{Q'(t)}{Q(t)}dt = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{12-t}{60} dt\implies .....$

Comment: There are three values for $P(t)$. The following four comments show that $P(t)$ can equal either $0$, $6$ or $12$.

Comment: $P^{\prime\prime}(t) = \frac{1}{5} \, \left(\frac{1}{5} \, P(t) - \frac{1}{60} \, P(t)^{2} \right)
- \frac{1}{30} \,  \left(\frac{1}{5} \, P(t)^{2} - \frac{1}{60} \, P(t)^{3} \right)$ ...

Comment: $=  -\frac{1}{1800} \, P(t) \Bigl(P(t)^{2} - 18P(t) + 72\Bigr)$ ...

Comment: $= -\frac{1}{1800} \, P(t) \Bigl(P(t) - 6\Bigr) \Bigl(P(t) - 12\Bigr) $.

Comment: So, $P^{\prime\prime}(t) = 0$ if, and only if, $P(t) = 0$, $P(t) = 6$, or $P(t) = 12$.